# Insert a group of consistent item with foreign key but colliding with existing items

Tags: postgresql, insert, sequence, postgresql-9.3

Is there a way to insert a group of items that are dependent but consistent between them with unique primary keys and foreign keys but that are colliding with items in database.

For example, given a table `A`:

```
id  primary key,
name
```

and a table `B`:

```
 id primary key,
 name,
 id_a'  -- foreign key on A
```

I want to insert:

```
INSERT INTO A(id, name) VALUES (1, "a");
INSERT INTO B(id, name, id_a) VALUES (1, "b", 1);
```

But the keys `A.id` or `B.id` could be taken already. Is there a way to insert my elements with auto setting key and foreign keys in a consistent way without colliding with existing elements?

Comment: Does this answer your question?: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/how-do-i-use-currval-in-postgresql-to-get-the-last-inserted-id/3282#3282

Comment: It won't help if there is several elements A and B.
Edit : maybe with variables

Comment: If you want to insert multiple rows in both tables, you can modify @Erwin's answer here: [How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key/46477#46477)

Comment: The paragraph titled **INSERT new FK rows at the same time** has a statement that uses table structure identical to yours.

Comment: The problem is that I have tables C, D, E, ... with foreign keys between them, I am not sure writing functions for cascading creation is scalable with 40 tables.

Answer (score 2):

In reference to [your comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52762/insert-a-group-of-consistent-item-with-foreign-key-but-colliding-with-existing-i#comment93449_52762), CTEs *are* scalable that way. You should do everything in a single transaction anyway. The related question @ypercube suggested should fit your case exactly:
[How do I insert a row which contains a foreign key?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key/46477)

Your other option would be to employ [`lastval()` and `curval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html#FUNCTIONS-SEQUENCE-TABLE) to identify  values most recently obtained from sequences. Not providing code, your question is too vague. These related questions on SO may be helpful:
[Reference value of serial column in another column during same INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433075/reference-value-of-serial-column-in-another-column-during-same-insert/12433446)
[PostgreSQL next value of the sequences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393604/postgresql-next-value-of-the-sequences%20/13394177)